# TikZ: align nodes like path

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I would like to have the numbers aligned like the path (and midway). 
But this only works at the number '1' here...

*Is there a trick or do I have to calculate angles?*

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\s{10}% 
\pgfmathsetmacro\R{1.7}
\pgfmathsetmacro\r{1.4}

\pgfmathsetmacro\Rout{\R/cos(180/\s)}% 
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize]
\node[shape=regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\s,
inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2cm*\r, draw,  
align=center, 
] (rad) {good at 1; \\ at 2,3,4,5 bad};

\node[shape=regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\s,
inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2cm*\Rout, draw, 
] (Rad) {};

\foreach \No in {1,...,5}{%%
\path[draw=red, ->] (rad.side \No) -- (Rad.side \No) node[inner sep=0pt, midway]{\No};
}%%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can calculate the angles, it's no so difficult:

```
rotate={360*(\No-1)/\s)}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\s{10}% 
\pgfmathsetmacro\R{1.7}
\pgfmathsetmacro\r{1.4}

\pgfmathsetmacro\Rout{\R/cos(180/\s)}% 
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize]
\node[shape=regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\s,
inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2cm*\r, draw,  
align=center, 
] (rad) {good at 1; \\ at 2,3,4,5 bad?};

\node[shape=regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\s,
inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2cm*\Rout, draw, 
] (Rad) {};

\foreach \No in {1,...,8}{%%
\path[draw=red, ->] (rad.side \No) -- (Rad.side \No) node[inner sep=0pt, midway, rotate={360*(\No-1)/\s)}]{\No};
}%%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I knew I could make this brute force by calculating angles. But I asked myself, whether there is a simple TikZ-like method. ;)

Comment: @cis, but  `360*(\No-1)/\s)` is a little bit more simple than `\No>ceil(\s/2)+1 ? -90 : 90` :P. Anyway, Zarko's solution (+1) with your addition is very good too. It was my first approach, with `sloped` too, but Zarko was faster

Comment: That's true.... Touché :)

Answer (score 7):

Like this?

**Edit (1):** Now arrows and numbers are around complete shape.

[image]

**Edit (2):** Original code can be wrie on more concise way by defining image elements styles and a wee bit reorgnised its code.

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\s{10}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\R{1.7}
\pgfmathsetmacro\r{1.4}

\pgfmathsetmacro\Rout{\R/cos(180/\s)}%
   \begin{tikzpicture}[
EL/.style = {% Edge Labels
             font=\small, sloped, rotate=#1},
RP/.style = {% Regular Poligon
             shape=regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\s, draw,
             minimum size=2cm*#1, inner sep=0pt,  
             align=center}
                    ]
\node[RP=\r] (rad) {good at 1; \\ at 2, 3, \dots  11 bad};
\node[RP=\R] (Rad) {};

\foreach \No in {2,...,5}
\path[draw=red, ->] (rad.side \No) -- node[EL=+90] {\No} (Rad.side \No);
\foreach \No in {1,6,7,...,10}
\path[draw=red, ->] (rad.side \No) -- node[EL=-90] {\No} (Rad.side \No);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ahhh, `sloped, rotate=90`... OK, thx.

Comment: But this becomes weird again, if I say `\foreach \No in {6,...,10}`. There it is `sloped, rotate=-90` needed, it seems. But I think, I can fix this.
`

Comment: I used it like this now:


`\foreach \No in {1,...,\s}{%%
\pgfmathsetmacro\Rot{\No>ceil(\s/2)+1 ? -90 : 90}
\path[draw=red] (Rad.side \No) -- (rad.side \No) node[inner sep=0pt, midway, sloped, rotate=\Rot]{\No};
}%%`

Comment: I think there's a key something like `allow upside down` that will fix the issue with going past the vertical.

Comment: @AndrewStacey,  thank you very much. I will check that late afternoon.